# How to accept cookies with robot framework?

Tags: python, html, css, robotframework

How to handle a cookie window and accpet it with robot framework? i tried to do it in this site: https://www.ibm.com/br-pt

and my code (to accept cookies):

```
Page should contain element  class=truste_box_overlay_border
sleep  5s
Click element  class="call"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following keyword definition

```
*** Keywords ***
Accept Cookies
     Wait Until Page Contains Element   ${ACCEPT_COOKIES_BUTTON}
     Click Element   ${ACCEPT_COOKIES_BUTTON}
     ${cookie_banner_closed}     Run Keyword And Return Status   Wait Until Page /*continued*/
     Does Not Contain Element   ${ACCEPT_COOKIES_BUTTON}     2s
     Run Keyword If      ${cookie_banner_closed}==False 
     Click Element   ${ACCEPT_COOKIES_BUTTON}
```